# Nil is not the empty list?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am learning Scheme and am using an online interpreter from repl.it. I am having some trouble understanding why this returns `#f`:

```scm
(eq? '() 'nil) ; ==> #f
```

Answer (score 6):

In LISP 1.5 `nil`, `'nil`, `'()` and `()`  evaluates to `nil`. The reader translated `()` and `nil` into the same singleton empty list and it is self evaluating so that the quote is optional. `nil` is also the only false value and all other values are truthy. The very first Scheme implementation was hosted by a commercial Lisp compatible with 1.5 and much of the host were used transparently in the first Scheme. Common Lisp is a descendant of 1.5 and still works like this, but Scheme has had changes from report to report and these are the rules from R5RS and later:

The empty list is `'()`. It's quoted and evaluates to `()`. It is not self evaluating so `()` is invalid Scheme code. `'nil` evalutes to `nil` which is a symbol and not the empty list. In Scheme the only false value is `#f` and thus the empty list is truthy.

In code:

```
'()            ; ==> () 
'(1 . (2 . ()) ; ==> (1 2)
()             ; ==>  ERROR: Illegal empty application (not allowed)
(eq? '() 'nil) ; ==> #f (empty list and nil are different values)
(if '() #t #f) ; ==> #t (empty list is truthy)
```

Comment: Perhaps this is nit-picking, but I would argue that the empty list '() *does* evaluate to itself. The fact that it's *printed* by "display" as "()" is, I claim, a historical mistake. The same applies to symbols such as 'nil.

Comment: @JohnClements The standard is clear on the fact that `'x` evaluates to `x`. But `x` does not evalute to `x` unless it's self evaluating. In racket `1` actually gets quoted in the fully expanded program while `()` is still illegal. `'()` evalues to `()` and thus rackets printing is `'()` since that evaluates to `()`. It's the chosen visualization, like printing numbers in hex rather than decimal, not a different value.

Comment: @JohnClements the form `'()` is not the empty list, it is `(quote ())`, and this *does* evaluate to `()`.  `()` is an error.

Comment: Your reduction semantics is different from mine. I claim mine is (a) consistent, and (b) simpler. Check out the stepper in DrRacket BSL to see what I mean.

Comment: @Sylwester respectfully disagree. The standard is clear that 'x evaluates to a particular symbol. The "display" function prints that value as the string "x". You're skipping a step when you say that 'x evaluates to x.

Comment: @JohnClements Even when you do `(display '())` in `#lang racket` you get `()`, which is exatly what the [R5RS standard](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.2) says: "`(quote <datum>)` evaluates to the datum value represented by `<datum>` ". `#lang racket` and `#!r6rs` works the same since they are decendants of R5RS. The only real difference is how the REPL chooses to represent values. This and the fact that top level programs are REPL-ed even when compiled I'm not that found of, but besides that I love Racket.

Comment: The empty list in Scheme is not `'()`; that's a quote expression which calculates the empty list as its result. The (printed representation of the) empty list is just `()`: that's exactly what is staring you in the face when you evaluate `'()`.  `'()` is the list `(quote ())` which is definitely not empty.

Comment: @JohnClements The quote is required in `'x` to obtain the symbol `x` itself in order that the unadorned expression `x` can serve the purpose of denoting the contents of the variable binding named by `x` that may exist in the surrounding environment.

Comment: @Kaz I don't want to prolong this, but I continue to assert that you and I are largely disagreeing about the behavior of the printer. More specifically, the stepper in BSL for DrRacket demonstrates a reduction semantics in which '() reduces to '() and in which 'x reduces to 'x. More generally, your formulation is incompatible with the notion of a reduction semantics generally, in which we must choose a set of terms that we call "values" that cannot be reduced any further. I'm happy to give you more details if you're actually interested.

Comment: @JohnClements Whatever that stepper is doing, it is not demonstrating the reading of an expression, evaluation, and simple printing of the subsequent value. I don't understand why you keep referring to this stepper; try `'()` in the **regular REPL** (read-eval-print-loop) of any Scheme implementation.  It could be that this stepper is deliberately taking values, and contriving an expression which produces those values, so that the output can be copy-and-pasted back. The expression which produces a value is not the same thing as that value, except for self-evaluating objects.

Comment: @JohnClements As for the behavior of the printer, that can be tested more directly by evaluating `(display '())`.  To print the empty list without involving the source code term `'()` we can compute the empty list by calling the `list` function with zero arguments: `(let ((empty (list))) (display empty))`.  It comes out as `()`, not `'()`.

Comment: It could happen I have yet to see the light, but I've made so many interpreters and compilers where `'` is never part of a literal. eg. `'"test"` and `'()` both gets read to `(quote "test")` and `(quote ())` and both gets evaluated to "the code" as data in the interpreter and for a compiler it gets constant folded to a data structure and it's reference is never subject to evaluation. A compiler never actually evaluates  arguments when all literals are handled, The self evaluating values would need the same treatment in a compiler. Where does my reasoning fail?

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion here is because the Racket printer is strange: it prints things with quotes by default (depending on the `print-as-expression` parameter).  So, for instance `(call-with-output-string (lambda (p) (display 'x p)))` returns `"x"` while (with normal settings of various parameters) `(call-with-output-string (lambda (p) (print 'x p)))` returns `"'x"`.  I can, sort-of, see why they did this, but it's annoying.

Comment: @tfb (all opinions personal) No! Not annoying! That's exactly the point! Let's ignore symbols and lists and quote for the moment, and consider simple strings, specifically the string containing the letters a, b, and c. Would you describe this string as "abc" or as abc? I think you'd describe it as "abc". Specifically, we use the double-quotes to indicate to ourselves that this is a string. But what do we get when we call (display "abc")? We get no quotes, just the letters abc. Does this mean that the string "abc" "evaluates to" abc? No, it doesn't. It just means that `display` doesnt display..

Comment: The quotes. Moving back to symbols, note that (display 'abc) produces exactly the same characters on the output as (display "abc"). Does that mean that "abc" and 'abc both evaluate to the same thing? No, it definitely does not. It just means that our chosen printer happens to print them in the same way. Let's now consider the "print" function. For "print", the printed representation is the same as the program term for both symbols *and* strings. This is why print is better than display or write for printing values.

Comment: Taking a step back and looking at the bigger picture, it's entirely reasonable to say that 'abc evaluates to 'abc, just like we say that "abc" evaluates to "abc"; they are both values, and need no further reduction.

Comment: @JohnClements: this is not the forum for this so I won't respond further but I disagree with what you're saying: I think you are confusing what `read` does with what the evaluator does and also various incidental properties of the printer (such as whether it prints readably or not).

Comment: R7RS in §4.1.2 states that "(quote [datum]) evaluates to [datum]".  That applies as much to (quote ()) and '() as it does to (quote a) or 'a. They evaluate to a literal constant.

Comment: @ChrisVine Basically the same as I mentioned earlier but I dictated R5RS since it is the common ancestor of both `lang #racket` as well as `#!r7rs` and this has not had changes for a while. Using strings might be more subtle. `"string"` is self evaluating but we can still quote it `'"string"` to stop it from self evaluation. `'"string"` i snot self evaluating as it becomes `"string"`. What `quote` does is universal. what `datum` is is whatever the reader made.